# Spring problems injecting Clock as a constructor argument

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a class that takes a java.time.Clock object as a constructor argument.
I am having problems defining this as a bean in the applicationContext.xml file:

TimeTracker.java

```
public class TimeTracker{

    public final Clock clock;
    public TimeTracker(Clock clock){
        this.clock = clock;
    }
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="timeTracker" 
        class="com.tracker.TimeTracker">
        <constructor-arg type="java.time.Clock" value=""/> 
</bean>
```

The error I am having is: Ambiguous constructor argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as constructor arguments?

Comment: do you have other constructors in the class time tracker?

Comment: no, I have no other constructor for the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
<bean class=“java.time.Clock” factory-method=“java.time.Clock.systemDefaultZone” name=“clock”/>

<bean id="timeTracker" 
    class="com.tracker.TimeTracker">
    <constructor-arg ref=“clock”/> 
</bean>
```

The `value` attribute is for primitive types only.

Comment: thanks for the explanation Strelok. I tried your answer , but I get the following: Could not instantiate bean class java.time.Clock: Is it an abstract class? This is true as Clock is an abstract class

Comment: Sorry I missed the fact that the Clock constructor is protected and you have to get an instance via a factory method. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate a clock and use it as a reference. Something similar to:

```
<bean id="clock" class="java.time.clock"/>
<bean id="timeTracker" 
    class="com.tracker.TimeTracker">
    <constructor-arg type="java.time.Clock" ref="clock"/> 
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<bean id="timeTracker" class="com.tracker.TimeTracker">
        <constructor-arg>
          <bean class="java.time.Clock" factory-method="java.time.Clock.systemUTC" /> 
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution from Strelok nearly works but it failed for me as you do not need to define the full path of the factory method. It is relative to the factory Class so if you type factory-method=“java.time.Clock.systemDefaultZone” it will look for a method in *java.time.Clock.java.time.Clock.systemDefaultZone()*.

```
<bean id="systemClock" class="java.time.Clock" factory-method="systemUTC" />

<bean id="timeTracker" class="com.tracker.TimeTracker">
    <constructor-arg type="java.time.Clock" ref="systemClock"/> 
</bean>
```

To makes things worse the Spring exception is not especially helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Strelok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2788/strelok)'s answer almost works, it should be -

```
<bean name=“clock” class=“java.time.Clock” factory-method=“systemDefaultZone” />
```